# Sitecore 10 update 1 using SIA Installation issue CX509PrivateKey::Create: Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: sitecore-client, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

While installing with Sitecore 10 update 1 using SIA facing an issue as below

`[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate ------------------] CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) [TIME] 00:00:06 CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)`

Even I tried to create new certificate using PowerShell command and there were no issue.

Please help.

Comment: I am facing same issue..any fix available_